emergence of quantum computing and its potential threat
Considering the emergence of quantum computing and its potential threat to cryptographic security, how might the Bitcoin network adapt and evolve to maintain its integrity and resilience in the face of this technological advancement, while preserving its core principles of decentralization and trustlessness?

Does this answer your question? Are there any plans to make Bitcoin quantum-resistant?
